# How to use multiple property-placeholder in a Spring xml file

Tags: java, spring

I have a question related to how Spring handles multiple property-placeholder.

I have this section of code:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:dir1/${myapp.system.property}.properties"/>
```

The property myapp.system.property is a defined System property.

If it is defined to "devsystem", for example, all the properties defined in devsystem.properties are imported and are available to use in the code below.

Now I wanted to have another property file whose name is defined by a properties in the devsystem.property file:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:dir1/${myapp.system.property}.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:dir2/myapp-${myapp.environment}.properties"/>
```

myapp.environment is a property defined in the devsystem.properties file.

This stopped working. Spring cannot resolve ${myapp.environment} and complains it cannot locate file  dir2/myapp-${myapp.environment}.properties.

Can someone let me know what I did wrong and how can I make this working?

Comment: You cannot as at that location only the system properties/environment is consulted the property placeholder doesn't replace placeholders in different locations. I would suggest instead of using your own property to use spring profiles or write an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to load the different property files.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file1.properties,classpath*:project-common.properties,classpath*:project-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"/>
```

In my case, it was a legacy system so property files didn't have some standard names but for sure you can use wildcards to reference your property files.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:file1.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:file2.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

or (comma separated)

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file1.properties,classpath:file2.properties"/>
```

Comment: Just a heads up: the property name is `locations` and the values must be included as children of an `<array>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Just 4 years late, but I found a way to do it in spring 4 (I'm using 4.2.2).

The trick is to use util:properties to wrap the 2 property files, and access the value included in the first file with [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

```
<util:properties 
      id="specific" 
      location="classpath:dir1/#{systemProperties['myapp.system.property']}.properties"/>
<util:properties 
      id="devProperties" 
      location="classpath:dir2/myapp-#{specific['myapp.environment']}.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="specific" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="devProperties" order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Using properties you have access to bean created.

ignore-unresolvable is the way to access both property-placeholders without having errors

Hope it helps someone from now on.